# Not reopening question based on whether edit was significant

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

I'd like to ask about those questions in reopen queue which get there due to an edit. My reasoning is that the edit possibly has improved the question and it may be now a workable question. Following this logic, sometimes I find useful to see if the question has been significantly changed due to an edit. IMO, there is no sense to reopen a question where someone has fixed a couple of typos and that's it. But just now I failed a review audit where all the editor did was to fix some indentation and apparently I should have reopened it. This made me think if I'm doing it right. Again, what I think is the question should only be reopened if it has been improved. If not, there is no reason to change its status.

Am I right? Or should I judge each question independently regardless of its edit history, that is asking myself "would I close this question if it was open? If not, then reopen."

Comment: Any chance you can link us to the failed audit? It could also be that the specific audit was bad.

Comment: Audit was on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473996/get-count-of-array-that-converted-to-dynamic-in-c-sharp I don't think it is a case of bad audit, just myself confused about things.

Comment: That's a horrible audit - not your fault there.

Comment: Plus, the question currently being open shows that others also thought it was worth reopening.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I think **horrible** is a bit of a stretch.  It is well written and contains all of the pertinent info, which is better than 50% of the recent questions on SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> should I judge each question independently regardless of its edit history, that is asking myself 'would I close this question if it was open? If not, then reopen'.

Yes, you should judge each question based on its current text, not based on what the last edit changed.

Comment: Exactly - reopening questions isn't about giving some editor an A for effort; it's about keeping good questions on the site, regardless of how they got that way.